# how to fix vulnerability found in gulp-sass.(tar is causing this )

Tags: npm, sass, gulp

I got he following error warning me to fix the tar vulnerability:

```
[!] 1 vulnerability found [7018 packages audited]
    Severity: 1 high    Run `npm audit` for more detail

>npm audit                                                                                
=== npm audit security report ===                        

Manual Review
Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve                                                                                                  Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance                 
  high            Arbitrary File Overwrite          

  Package         tar                                                           
  Dependency of   gulp-sass [dev]                                               
  Path            gulp-sass > node-sass > node-gyp > tar                        

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/803                        

[!] 1 vulnerability found - Packages audited: 7018 (627 dev, 97 optional)
    Severity: 1 high
```

I would like to know how I can fix this within another package like here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove tar from a required section in node-gyp in package-lock.json and replace the version in the dependencies section to `^4.4.2` or higher